# Getting below errors while calling google firebase api. How to solve this

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**OPTIONS** https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send 404 ()

> Failed to load https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.

```
{readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ,
 setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
```

**XHR failed loading**: OPTIONS "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send".

here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'key=*********'
          },
          data: {
                 "to" : '*****************************',
                 "data" : {
                     "phone" : "99*****",
                     "id" : "5****"
                        }

                 },
          success: function(response){
            console.log("success");
          },
            error : function(response) {
                console.log(response);                   
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing a cross-domain request. In order for the browser to know that this is allowed, it will first execute `OPTIONS` call to ask the server if this `method` for this `endpoint` will allow it. This request in your case failed and therefore the actual `POST` cannot be executed.

Bottom line I don't think the request you are trying to execute is meant to be called from within browser as you are revealing credentials and should be executed only from backend.

Comment: Good catch Peter! That last paragraph is very important. The code exposes the FCM server key to all users of the web page. As its name implies, the FCM server key is only to be used on a server (or otherwise trusted environment), as anyone who has that key can send notifications to your users on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks Peter & Frank